# How to take a string and arrange words in alphabetical order using C

Tags: c

I'm stuck. I've got quite a big programming assignment and most of it looks easy, the part I'm stuck on is splitting a string of text into individual words in an array and then sorting them in alphabetical order.

E.g. if the string contained the following: "I am stuck. Please help me stack exchange" it would save the words in an array and output them in the following order:

```
am
exchange
help
i
me
please
stack
stuck
```

Could you guys please help?

EDIT: Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "This is a test String, anything else? lol";
    char *hhh;

    int i;
    for(i=0;str[i];i++){
        str[i]=tolower(str[i]); //Converts the string to lower case
    }

    //Breaks the string into separate words based on spaces and some
    //punctuation (Anything which signals the end of a word)
    hhh = strtok(str," ,.-:;?!");

    while(hhh != NULL){
        printf("%s \n",hhh);
        hhh = strtok(NULL, " ,.-:;?!");
    }

}
```

As you can see I've converted the words into lower case r and I can output them but I have no idea how to sort them in alphabetical order. Looked into bubble sorting and I understand it but I don't understand how to use it to accomplish what I need.

Comment: `strtok()` and some sorting algorithm

Comment: First parse the string and separate the words. Then convert everything to lowercase. Then use a bubble sorting algorithm (you can find it on the internet, it's very easy to implement) to compare the first letter of the words and that's it. In this case, you can directly compare letters, since everything is lower case (which means the letters that come later in the alphabet will have a higher ASCII value).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Apologies. Updated with what I have so far

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My code is pretty "manual" meaning that I don't use stuff like `strtok` or `tolower`. I manually loop through everything myself. If you don't like that, just replace the corresponding parts with those functions. Here you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _WLEN   32  // maximum length of each word
#define _NWORDS 256 // maximum number of words in the sentence

void word_swap(char** w1, char** w2);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char* sentence      = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."; // the sentence

    char to_ignore[10]  = ".,-\"'!?()";             // characters that are ignored
    char words[_NWORDS][_WLEN];                     // words will be stored here
    int i, j, k=0, l=0, word_count, swapped=0;      // some variables that will be needed

    /* First we loop through the sentence to separate the words */
    for (i=0; i<_NWORDS*_WLEN; i++) {
        /* If we reach the end of the sentence, finish up the last word with '\0' and quit the loop */
        if (*(sentence+i) == '\0') {
            words[k][l] = '\0';
            word_count = k+1;
            break;
        }
        /* Check if the current character is one that we want to ignore. If so, skip to the next character. */
        for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
            if (to_ignore[j] == *(sentence+i)) goto END_FOR;
        }
        /* If the current character is not a space, add it to a word */
        if (*(sentence+i) != ' ') {
            words[k][l] = *(sentence+i);
            l++;
        }
        /* ... if it is a space, finish the current word with '\0' and move to the next word */
        else {
            words[k][l] = '\0';
            k++;
            l=0;
        }
    END_FOR:;
    }

    /* Convert everything to lowercase so it's easy to sort the words */
    for (i=0; i<word_count; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<_WLEN; j++) {
            if (words[i][j] == '\0') break;
            /* If the letter is uppercase (ASCII codes 65-90) then add 32 to it, which is the lowercase variant */
            if (words[i][j] >= 65 && words[i][j] <= 90) words[i][j] += 32;
        }
    }

    /* Bubble sort the words in alphabetical order */
    do {
        for (i=0; i<word_count-1; i++) {
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[i+1]) > 0) {
                word_swap(&words[i], &words[i+1]);
                swapped = 1;
                break;
            } else swapped = 0;
        }
    } while (swapped != 0);

    /* Print the words on the screen */
    for (i=0; i<word_count; i++) printf("%s\n", words[i]);
}

void word_swap(char** w1, char** w2) {
    char tmp[_WLEN];
    memcpy(&tmp, w1, _WLEN);
    memcpy(w1, w2, _WLEN);
    memcpy(w2, &tmp, _WLEN);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good, the only problem is the output is wrong. Compile it and you'll notice the words "adamo" and "hell" so something is going wrong. Also is there a way to make the "Char to_ignore" variable the base of the split? E.g. if I have a sentence such as: "roll the boat, steal some food! take a nap? awesome." it would split the words not based on the fact that it contains spaces only but also based on the punctuation? Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: You're on windows, right? I compiled and ran this on OS X in Xcode and everything is fine here. Visual Studio uses a different compiler, which might cause those bugs. I have no idea why though :(

Comment: Okay, I know what's the deal. `sizeof` somehow doesn't give the same results on Windows. I think it's okay to just use `_WLEN` in `memcpy` since every word has '\0' at its end anyway. I edited the code! Hope it's good now :)

Comment: Just as a sidenote: I love when people randomly downvote an answer without posting their own... [congrats on that, whoever downvoted this](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/27/27fb4259167f556f1fa83f2378e70af72081c5b2d3f44bff1e33fcb20cbddeee.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return strcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
}

int main(){
    char str[] = "This is a test String, anything else? lol";
    char *word, *words[strlen(str)/2+1];
    int i, n;

    for(i=0;str[i];i++){
        str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
    }

    i=0;
    word = strtok(str, " ,.-:;?!");

    while(word != NULL){
        words[i++] = word;
        word = strtok(NULL, " ,.-:;?!");
    }

    n = i;
    qsort(words, n, sizeof(*words), cmp);

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
        puts(words[i]);

    return 0;
}
```